# Create a set with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a big list of items, and some auxiliary data. For each item in the list and element in data, I compute some thing, and add all the things into an output set (there may be many duplicates). In code:

```
def process_list(myList, data):
    ret = set()
    for item in myList:
        for foo in data:
            thing = compute(item, foo)
            ret.add(thing)
    return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = create_data()
    myList = create_list()
    what_I_Want = process_list(myList, data)
```

Because myList is big and compute(item, foo) is costly, I need to use multiprocessing. For now this is what I have:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

initialize_worker(bar):
    global data
    data = bar

def process_item(item):
    ret = set()
    for foo in data:
        thing = compute(item, foo)
        ret.add(thing)
    return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = create_data()
    myList = create_list()
    p = Pool(nb_proc, initializer = initialize_worker, initiargs = (data))
    ret = p.map(process_item, myList)
    what_I_Want = set().union(*ret)
```

What I do not like about that is that ret can be big. I am thinking about 3 options:

1) Chop myList into chunks a pass them to the workers, who will use process_list on each chunk (hence some duplicates will be removed at that step), and then union all the sets obtained to remove the last duplicates.

**question:** Is there an elegant way of doing that? Can we specify to Pool.map that it should pass the chunks to the workers instead of each item in the chunks? I know I could chop the list by myself, but this is damn ugly.

2) Have a shared set between all processes.

**question**: Why multiprocessing.manager does not feature set()? (I know it has dict(), but still..) If I use a manager.dict(), won't the communications between the processes and the manager slow down considerably the thing?

3) Have a shared multiprocessing.Queue(). Each worker puts the things it computes into the queue. Another worker does the unioning until some stopItem is found (which we put in the queue after the p.map)

**question:** Is this a stupid idea? Are communications between processes and a multiprocessing.Queue faster than those with a, say, manager.dict()? Also, how could I get back the set computed by the worker doing the unioning?

Comment: I won't add this as an answer because `Javier`'s answer I think already covers what's needed. I would personally use `mp.Queue` mainly because I think it's clearer and maybe gives a little bit more control over the whole process. In terms of what is fastest, that's highly dependent on the actual compute load, if each call to `computeThing` takes an hour then the overhead from managed data structures are likely to be negligible. So for you to know what is best, you need to test it on your specific load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor thing: `initiargs` takes a tuple.

If you want to avoid creating all the results before reducing them into a `set`, you can use `Pool.imap_unordered()` with some chunk size. That will produce chunk size results from each workers as they become available.

If you want to change `process_item` to accept chunks directly, you have to do it manually. `toolz.partition_all` could be used to partition the initial dataset.

Finally, the managed data structures are bound to have much higher synchronization overhead. I'd avoid them as much as possible.

Go with `imap_unordered` and see if that's good enough; if not, then partition; if you cannot help having more than a couple duplicates total, use a managed dict.

Comment: Or `Pool.imap_unordered()` which is usually a little faster then `imap()` as it does not need to care about the return order, and they end up in an unordered container anyway.

Comment: Good idea, I'll amend my answer!

Comment: Thanks! That's nice I didn't know that imap (and imap_unordered) yields results as soon as they are ready. However with this approach, it seems that Pool.imap_unordered() will still be big anyway, as at some point the whole iterable is computed in memory. Is there a way to make it a generator, forgetting the results as soon as it yields them?

Comment: It is a generator.